# Having trouble getting values from an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, javascript-objects

I am making a program to get user input from HTML forms and compile them into an object for each user. So, I have an HTML form, I make a constructor, then I set up a click event to make the object, then I put it in the variable, and then I am trying to put that variable in an array of objects, before finally using a for loop to get all of the information from each object in this array. However, I am having trouble with that last part (or at least I think). Every time I run the code, the console log does display the message, but it is coming up with undefined rather than the user input. Can someone help please?

```js
function user(firstName, lastName, address) {
  user.firstName = firstName;
  user.lastName = lastName;
  user.address = address;
}

var users = [];

document.addEventListener("submit", function(addUser) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var newUser = new user(
    document.getElementById("userFName").value,
    document.getElementById("userLName").value,
    document.getElementById("userAdd").value
  );

  users.push(newUser);

  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    console.log("User" + (i + 1) + "'s first name is " + users[i].firstName + ", their last name is " + users[i].lastName + ", and their address is " + users[i].address);
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>WWW</title>

  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <input id="userFName" placeholder="First Name">
    <input id="userLName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input id="userAdd" placeholder="Address">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you just need a `return user` iat the end n your user function

Comment: @ControlAltDel Not needed when used with `new`.

Comment: your `user` class is adding the values to the constructor, rather than the instance ... use `this.firstName = firstName;` etc instead

Answer (score 1):

By assigning to `user`, you're assigning to a property of the constructor, not a property of the instance. `new User` will mutate the constructor and return an empty object whose internal prototype is `user.prototype`.

Assign to `this` instead inside the constructor, to change the instance that gets returned.

```js
function user(firstName, lastName, address) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.address = address;
}

var users = [];

document.addEventListener("submit", function(addUser) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var newUser = new user(
    document.getElementById("userFName").value,
    document.getElementById("userLName").value,
    document.getElementById("userAdd").value
  );

  users.push(newUser);

  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    console.log("User" + (i + 1) + "'s first name is " + users[i].firstName + ", their last name is " + users[i].lastName + ", and their address is " + users[i].address);
  }

});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="userFName" placeholder="First Name">
  <input id="userLName" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input id="userAdd" placeholder="Address">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or use a plain object instead of a constructor.

```js
const user = (firstName, lastName, address) => ({
  firstName, lastName, address
});
const users = [];

document.addEventListener("submit", function(addUser) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var newUser = user(
    document.getElementById("userFName").value,
    document.getElementById("userLName").value,
    document.getElementById("userAdd").value
  );

  users.push(newUser);

  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    console.log("User" + (i + 1) + "'s first name is " + users[i].firstName + ", their last name is " + users[i].lastName + ", and their address is " + users[i].address);
  }

});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="userFName" placeholder="First Name">
  <input id="userLName" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input id="userAdd" placeholder="Address">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If using a constructor I'd also suggest (convention) capitalising the name: `User`.

Answer (score 0):

make your life easier, use names in your forms!

```js
const
  myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, users  = []
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()

  users.push({ firstName: myForm.userFName.value
             , lastName : myForm.userLName.value
             , address  : myForm.userAdd.value
            })

  console.clear()
  users.forEach( (user,i) => console.log(i,JSON.stringify(user)) )

  myForm.reset()  // clear inputs 
  myForm.userFName.focus()
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input name="userFName" placeholder="First Name" required >
  <input name="userLName" placeholder="Last Name"  required >
  <input name="userAdd"   placeholder="Address"    required >
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```